# How to use variables to control document path?

Tags: python, pandas, import

I writing a code which have two variables.One for the document name, the other for document path.
Here is the code I am using.

```
    
    ym =(input("plz enter year&month(year for 4 + monyh for 2)："))    #ex:202207
    your_file=r"C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\jupyter\05_parice\202207_import.pdf"  # HERE IS 202207
```

I want to let `ym` 's number change the `your_file` document path to open and read in pandas .

txs everyone seeing

Comment: `your_file = fr"C:\Users\{var}.txt"` works just fine.

Comment: OH TXS,that's the idel I  want to do!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to interpolate the variable in the file path name. You can use f-strings and put the variable between `{}.`

```
your_file=f"{ym}_import.pdf" # just writing the relevant part since I am on MacOS.
```

Comment: Thanks,it can work, but I also want to know how to use f-strongs in writing in absolute path.